# Use a list of dynamic names in a for loop in r

Tags: r, for-loop, gbm

I have a list of variable names of the form LM_1_1, LM_1_2, LM_1_3, LM_2_1, LM_2_2, LM_2_3 etc, and I want to use them in a for loop.

I created the following code but the `paste` function is for creating characters and it doesn't work. Would be greatly appreciated if you could help me.

```
for (i in seq(1,6,1) ){
for (j in seq(1,4,1)){

Pr_name <- paste("Prediction",i,j, sep = "_")

predictionTest<-predict(paste("LM",i,j,sep="_"),cd_test[cd_test$Pclass==i&cd_test$consumer==i,],
gbm.perf(paste("LM",i,j,sep="_"),method='cv'))

assign(Pr_name, predictionTest)

}}
```

Comment: you can use `get("LM_1_1")` and that should get what you want.

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Please, no! Use `mget` to put all those individual `LM` objects in a single data structure. And either use a `for` loop or `lapply` and ditch `assign`.

Comment: Yes -`mget` is better - and avoid the nested loops if possible.